# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$diffi_lvl_name

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting error in **Laravel 5.7** while creating relationship, I have created a relationship as: **Question.php:**

```
public function diffi_lvl() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DifficultyLevel');
}
```

and **DifficultyLevel.php:**

```
public function questions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
}
```

after that I used:

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
    {{ dd($question->diffi_lvl()->diffi_lvl_name) }}
@endforeach
```

and **QuestionController.php:**

```
public function index()
{
    $questions = Question::all();
    return view('questions.index', compact('questions'));
}
```

**difficulty level migration:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('difficulty_levels', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('diffi_lvl_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**and the question migration:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('question');
        $table->unsignedInteger('difficulty_level_id');
        $table->foreign('difficulty_level_id')->references('id')->on('difficulty_levels');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

but it's giving me this error as;

**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$diffi_lvl_name**

> **Note:** I also used this `{{ dd($question->diffi_lvl->diffi_lvl_name) }}` getting **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: Could you show us your models' schema?

Comment: Yeah I edited chk now

Comment: Thanks. I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your relationship as follows:

```
public function diffi_lvl() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DifficultyLevel', 'difficulty_level_id');
}

public function questions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question', 'difficulty_level_id');
}
```

Then, the following should work:

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
    {{ dd($question->diffi_lvl->diffi_lvl_name) }}
@endforeach
```

For more information, read the documentation on [Defining Relationships.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Edit: Actually, it seems just doing the following should work:

```
public function diffi_lvl() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DifficultyLevel', 'difficulty_level_id');
}

public function questions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
}
```

Comment: I think you are doing wrong relationship as question belongs to 1 diffi_level and difficulty level has many question, is it not?

Comment: BTW thanks for the answer it's now working like a charm, can you tell me what's the role of adding `difficulty_level_id` in relationshp???

Comment: Since you defined the method name as `diffi_lvl`, Laravel will try to look for `diffi_lvl_id` on your table, which does not exists. So you'd have to explicitly define another foreign key. It's mentioned in the documentation. Good luck :)

Comment: no need to change the relationship just added foreign key as question belongs to 1 diffi_level and difficulty level has many question, is it not?

Comment: The relationships are fine. You just need to specify the foreign key yes.

Answer (score 1):

You already fixed first error with using

```
$question->diffi_lvl->diffi_lvl_name
```

And for second error there are some possibilities.

- There is no DifficultyLevel attached to your Question model
- We have to see your table structure.Maybe you mapped wrongly your foreign keys.Is your foreign key named "difficulty_level_id" in "questions" table?